# Hole Punching with nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, tcp

Assume you have network A which allows connections to network B but not in the reverse direction. Is it possible to establish a connection from A to B such that a proxy running in B can now listen and serve connections within B back to A?

Example: HTTP Server A1 on port 8080 in network A is "invisible" to clients in network B. But a special client PA in network A connects to a proxy PB in network B and keeps the connection open such that the proxy PB can now listen on port 8080 and forward the request to the original HTTP Server A1.`

Ideally 2 nodeJS scripts could achieve functionality PA and PB.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Use the `http-proxy` module:

```
var http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
//
// Create your proxy server and set the target in the options.
//
httpProxy.createProxyServer({target:'http://PB:8080'}).listen(8080); // See (†)

//
// Create your target server
//
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.write('why hello there PA' + '\n' + JSON.stringify(req.headers, true, 2));
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#setup-a-basic-stand-alone-proxy-server

From there it's a matter of "proxy-inception" to get your desired result (I had a bit of a hard time tracking it exactly).